# Table and Synonym of the same table produce different results

Tags: sql, oracle, erp, row-level-security

In OracleEBS, there are modules like, AP, AR, XLA etc. Each module has its own schema named the same as the corresponding module name. There's also the APPS schema. You can access different tables from different schema via a synonym for that objects created in the APPS schema. For example, there's a table in xla schema named xla.xla_transaction_entities and the table has a synonym in apps schema. That's, the following two select queries should produce identical result set:

```
select distinct entity_code from xla.xla_transaction_entities
```

and

```
select distinct entity_code from apps.xla_transaction_entities
```

However, the second query produced less results than the first one. Then, I dropped and recreated the apps.xla_transaction_entities synonym. Only after recreating the synonym, the above two queries produced identical result sets. 
The question is, why would it happen? What caused the synonym to produce different result set? As far as I know, synonyms are just that - synonyms. As the name implies they should produce the same result set as their corresponding tables.

Edit:
In another test instance, I reproduced the same problem:

```
select distinct entity_code from apps.xla_transaction_entities
```

produces the following:

```
THIRD_PARTY_MERGE
MANUAL
INTER_ASSET_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTIONS
DEPRECIATION
```

---

```
select distinct entity_code from xla.xla_transaction_entities
```

produces the following:

```
AP_PAYMENTS
RCV_ACCOUNTING_EVENTS
THIRD_PARTY_MERGE
MANUAL
ADJUSTMENTS
PURCHASE_ORDER
MTL_ACCOUNTING_EVENTS
RECEIPTS
INTER_ASSET_TRANSACTIONS
AP_INVOICES
TRANSACTIONS
DEPRECIATION
```

---

```
  select * from dba_synonyms
  where synonym_name = 'XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES'
```

gives me the following:

```
OWNER   SYNONYM_NAME              TABLE_OWNER   TABLE_NAME,               DB_LINK
APPS    XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES  XLA           XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES
```

---

```
select * from dba_synonyms
where TABLE_NAME = 'XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES'
```

outputs the following:

```
OWNER    SYNONYM_NAME                   TABLE_OWNER    TABLE_NAME               DB_LINK
APPS     XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES       XLA            XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES
APPS     XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES_UPG   XLA            XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES
```

So, you can see that APPS.XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITES points to XLA.XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES. And again, once I recreate the synonym, the problem is gone. 
The reason why this bothers me so much is because most of the customized reports we have coded used synonyms instead of actual table names. So, I am wondering whether unless I recreate all synonyms in the APPS schema the problem will persist or not.

Comment: Before dropping and recreating the synonym it would have been advisable to check DBA_SYNONYMS to see what it was pointing to, then that might have shed light on the matter.

Comment: Required information is provided as an edition to the question.

Comment: My point was for future reference to view this data before the synonym is dropped if anything similar happens again. As for the rest of them,  you could perhaps check for all rows in DBA_SYNONYMS where the synonym_name != table_name as a start.

Comment: Oracle Applications uses fine grain access control (a.k.a. virtual private
database). The general construct is that an application context is set by an
Oracle applications user at the time of login and it has a security policy.

Answer (score 1):

Some tables in Oracle applications have VPD enabled. [In this link you can find additional information](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2243)

```
Are you using MO view like ap_invoices?
  For all org_ids' data      -> Use `ap_invoices_all`
  For specific org_id's data -> 11i -> `dbms_application_info.set_client_info(&org_id);`
                                R12 -> `mo_global.set_policy_context('S',&org_id);`
```

---

```
Are you using VPD enabled tables like xla_transaction_entities?
  For specific application's data -> xla_security_pkg.set_security_context(&appl_id);
  For all applications' data      -> xla_security_pkg.set_security_context(602);
                                    (Or) Use xla.xla_transaction_entities
                                    (Or) Use xla_transaction_entities_upg
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xla_transaction_entities` table is *VPD(Virtual Private Database)* enable .

*VPD* is a security feature which allows user to restrict accessing data from database at database level. Suppose a user is restricted to fetch data from application but he can use tools like SQLPlus to fetch data from table. To restrict this, the security administrator adds a security level(One of 3 types)
does not all the rows/column are fetched .

so instead of using `apps.xla_transaction_entities` use `xla.xla_transaction_entities`.

for [more info on VPD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution for this issue is to use the synonym `apps.xla_transaction_entities_upg`

This doesn't require us to bypass the security settings set on the `xla_transaction_entities`.

Source - Metalink Note : 2110926.1